# Check if browser can render heavy HTML

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have to render a dashboard that consists of several widgets (charts/tables), some of which may be really heavy.
Sometimes the HTML is so heavy that it causes freeses or page crashes, and it depends on the performance of a PC - the same page runs smoothly on a powerful PC and is laggy on others.

What I want:
calculate/estimate number of widgets in the dashboard that can be shown without problems, if this number is lesser than total number of widgets then show stubs, something like

> Click to show, may cause performance loss

instead of excessive widgets.

I want a cross-browser solution, but if there is none then any solution for popular browsers will suffice.

Comment: The solution, and you won't like this, is to optimize your widgets. 
Data wise: You could use a paged solution, so not all data is loaded in bulk in you widgets.
If that is not an option, you could use Lazy Loading on your DOM objects. Tables with 10.000 of records for example, should not put all elements in the DOM, but only the ones in the visible area (with some margin). During scrolling, the data that becomes invisible should be dropped from the DOM and the new visible data should be added.

Comment: It is already done: tables and pivot grids render only visible cells, charts decimate data on zoom. Widgets have settings that allow users to see more detailed charts at the expense of performance and I'm looking if it is possible to adjust those settings automatically by estimating PC performance from JS.

Comment: Interesting question - the only suggestion I can think of is to do live profiling before the real page loads.

Perhaps try to somehow create a JS payload, render that measuring the time it takes to render with `performance.timing.navigationStart` but with a loading layer infront with some message like "Estimating performance". Even that might be hard to do; not sure if it will correlate to the real workload. Then if the performance test takes more than n seconds you will show a warning or whatever.